# Capture a screenshot of activity and saving on sdcard

Tags: android

I am trying to take a screenshot of activity so it can be seen in the gallery. However the code is not working and image does not show in the gallery.I am calling method takePicSave() in the button click event.
Also in the manifest file, permission is there.

```
   private void takePicSave()
    {

        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(bitmap);

    }

      public Bitmap takeScreenshot(){

        View rootview = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootview.getDrawingCache();

      }

      public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){

        Date date = new Date() ; 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());


          File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , dateFormat.format(date) + " .png");
          FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Error " , e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error ", e.getMessage(), e);
            }


        }



      }
```

The error which I am getting
"java.io.FileNotFoundException/mnt/sdcard/2014-04-16.png(permission denied)

Comment: read and write permission are in your manifest?

Comment: currently I only have write permission in the manifest

Comment: The image is shown in the gallery of android 2.2, 4.0 and 4.1 but fails on 4.4, 2.3 and 2.2. Why is it working on some and not on others? Please help me understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this , in one of my project you can try below function

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenShotOfCurrentSticky(Activity activity,View v)
    {
        View view = v;
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
        int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        System.out.println("~~~~Bitmap frm Screen shot"+b);
        return b;
    }
```

I have put this function in Application class so passing activity object and view of which we wanna take screen shot. You can make changes according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the permission to read and write external storage in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I did add the permission to read now, but still no image is shown in gallery

Comment: 04-17 03:43:05.292: E/Error(377): /mnt/sdcard/2014-04-17 .png (Permission denied)
04-17 03:43:05.292: E/Error(377): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/2014-04-17 .png (Permission denied)
04-17 03:43:05.292: E/Error(377):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
04-17 03:43:05.292: E/Error(377):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
04-17 03:43:05.292: E/Error(377):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
04-17 03:43:05.292: E/Error(377):